# GitHub BuildPipeline for Dotnet Core on Linux fails without changes since last run; requests install or update of .NET

Tags: .net, github, .net-core, github-actions

I tried to add changes to my code and the build pipeline for Linux stopped working. The ones for Windows and Mac succeed.

I reverted all changes, so there are **no changes** except for comments since the last PullRequest which succeeded.

Now it fails with the following message: (Short: "*You must install or update .NET to run this application.*")

```
Build started 11/20/2022 12:32:08.
     1>Project "/home/runner/work/isoxml-dotnet/isoxml-dotnet/isoxml_dotnet.sln" on node 1 (VSTest target(s)).
     1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
         Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
Test run for /home/runner/work/isoxml-dotnet/isoxml-dotnet/{package}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/{package}.dll (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 17.3.1 (x64)
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
Testhost process for source(s) '/home/runner/work/isoxml-dotnet/isoxml-dotnet/{package}.Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/{package}.Test.dll' exited with error: You must install or update .NET to run this application.
App: /home/runner/.nuget/packages/microsoft.testplatform.testhost/16.9.4/lib/netcoreapp2.1/testhost.dll
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.0' (x64)
.NET location: /usr/share/dotnet/
The following frameworks were found:
  6.0.10 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=x64&rid=ubuntu.22.04-x64
. Please check the diagnostic logs for more information.

Test Run Aborted.
     1>Done Building Project "/home/runner/work/isoxml-dotnet/isoxml-dotnet/isoxml_dotnet.sln" (VSTest target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
```

My Build Pipeline looks like this:

```
name: .NET

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  buildLinux:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        dotnet-version: ['3.0', '3.1.x', '5.0.x','6.0.x' ]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v2
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build Linux
      run: dotnet build --no-restore
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-build --verbosity normal
  buildWindows:

    runs-on: windows-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        dotnet-version: ['3.0', '3.1.x', '5.0.x','6.0.x' ]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v2
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build Windows
      run: dotnet build --no-restore
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-build --verbosity normal
  buildMac:

    runs-on: macos-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        dotnet-version: ['3.0', '3.1.x', '5.0.x','6.0.x' ]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v2
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build Mac
      run: dotnet build --no-restore
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-build --verbosity normal
```

Please recognize that there are no changes in the dotnet.yml

What I tried so far:

- Revert all changes; everything left is just comments
- Change version of actions/setup-dotnet to v3, v3.0.2, v2.0.1

**Remark on Edit**: I removed the PackageName with {package} as it's not relevant for the solution. Hope that's OK ;)

Comment: In the yaml you posted you don't actually pass the version you want to use to the setup-dotnet action.

Answer (score 2):

Not a surprise as GitHub is rolling out Ubuntu 22.04 as `ubuntu-latest` between Oct 3 and Dec 1, 2022,

https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/6399

It seems that your workflow is somehow enrolled.

If you take a look at the contents of Ubuntu 22.04 image, you can see that .NET Core 3.1 runtime is not there,

https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md

.NET Core 3.1 is going to reach end of life in just a few days, so please upgrade your projects to .NET 6 at least. It simply makes no sense to target old runtimes.

If you do want to set up old runtimes you might use,

```yaml
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: |
          3.1.x
          5.0.x
          6.0.x
```

https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib/blob/12.5.1/.github/workflows/dotnetcore.yml#L28

Comment: Thanks for the info, this was indeed part of my problem :)

Comment: Since the builds run in matrix, passing all desired frameworks to the setup-dotnet as a list may take extra time downloading and extracting a bunch of frameworks that aren't used in that run. But the fact the framework version isissing is indeed causing the issue.

Comment: @jessehouwing I hope you spent some time on the actual MSBuild log, as that's simply a project targeting .NET Core 3.1 alone. So the matrix part in manifest was probably copied from another file and useless here in the context while this guy had no idea what's that. That's why I wrote this answer instead of commenting under yours.

Comment: I just assumed they copied that from the very first failing job in the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Your Azure Pipelines YAML calls the setup-dotnet action, but won't actually pass it a version to. That will just select the default version on the OS image.

Make sure you pass your matrix variable:

```
- uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
  with:
    dotnet-version:  ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
```

My guess is they stripped a number of no longer supported dotnet SDKs from the image now that dotnet 7 has been released.